# IPCThreadState: getAndExecuteCommand(fd=7) returned unexpected error -2147483648, aborting

Tags: android

I run my native service in android, The `mytestDaemon` is my native service daemon;  when I turn off screen, at some time point it happened below errors:

```
Exception Log Time:[Thu Nov  5 00:45:54 CST 2015] [28318.677552]

Exception Class: Native (NE)
Exception Type: SIGABRT

Current Executing Process: 
  pid: 351, tid: 351
  /system/bin/mytestDaemon

Backtrace: 
    #00 pc 0003b214  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00017861  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00018477  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00014cbd  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 00013010  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 0001f9c3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+94)
    #06 pc 000035f0  /system/bin/mytestDaemon
    #07 pc 00012ec1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
    #08 pc 000032f8  /system/bin/mytestDaemon

$** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Exception *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **$
```

It seems like the binder is dead. I see my function called binder, but didn't return back.

```
Parcel data, reply;

data.writeInterfaceToken(IFingerPrint::getInterfaceDescriptor());

remote()->transact(TRANSACTION_TEST_CANCEL, data, &reply);  //here, didn't call into remote service function
return reply.readInt32();
```

After then, the daemon is killed by android system.

```
11-05 00:45:54.430   351   351 E IPCThreadState: getAndExecuteCommand(fd=7) returned unexpected error -2147483648, aborting
11-05 00:45:54.430   351   351 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 351 (mytestDaemon)
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : $===AEE===AEE===AEE===$
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 0 poll events 1 revents 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : not know revents:0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 1 poll events 1 revents 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : not know revents:0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 2 poll events 1 revents 1
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : aed_main_fork_worker: generator 0xf6837148, worker 0xffb4f138, recv_fd 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 3 poll events 1 revents 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : not know revents:0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 4 poll events 1 revents 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : not know revents:0
11-05 00:45:54.430 25215 25215 I AEE/AED : handle_request(0)
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : p 5 poll events 0 revents 0
11-05 00:45:54.430 22054 22054 D AEE/AED : not know revents:0
11-05 00:45:54.432   347   962 I TFA9890 : tfa9890_SpeakerOn : 1070 : err = 0x00000000 tries = 1
11-05 00:45:54.433 25215 25215 I AEE/AED : check process 351 name:mytestDaemon
11-05 00:45:54.434   347   962 D TFA9890 : [tfa9890_SpeakerOn: 1075]tfa9890_SpeakerOn: 1075:err = 0x00000000 status val:0xc25f mtp val:0x0003
11-05 00:45:54.434 25215 25215 I AEE/AED : tid 351 abort msg address is:0x00000000, si_code is:-6 (request from 351:1000)
11-05 00:45:54.435 25215 25215 I AEE/AED : BOOM: pid=351 uid=1000 gid=1000 tid=351
11-05 00:45:54.435 25215 25215 I AEE/AED : [OnPurpose Redunant in void preset_info(aed_report_record*, int, int)] pid: 351, tid: 351, name: mytestDaemon  >>> /system/bin/mytestDaemon <<<
```

The stack is here (from android log _exp_detail.txt):

```
pid: 351, tid: 351, name: mytestDaemon  >>> /system/bin/mytestDaemon <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 00000000  r1 0000015f  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 f77dde38  r5 00000006  r6 00000019  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000000  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp ffc4117c
    ip 0000015f  sp ffc41078  lr f76c8865  pc f76ec214  cpsr 600f0010
    d0  ffffffffffffffff  d1  20444e414d4d4f66
    d2  0000010000000164  d3  000000000000013d
    d4  f6c79100f6c79100  d5  0000000000000000
    d6  3020302030203020  d7  3020302030203020
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 f6c79200f6c79200  d17 0000000000000000
    d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
    d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 00000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0003b214  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00017861  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00018477  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00014cbd  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 00013010  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 0001f9c3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+94)
    #06 pc 000035f0  /system/bin/mytestDaemon
    #07 pc 00012ec1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
    #08 pc 000032f8  /system/bin/mytestDaemon
```

Why is the binder did't call into that remote function, and why the daemon is killed ?
Thank you for help for this.

appended mytestdaemon source code

```
sp<ProcessState> Proc(ProcessState::self());
sp<IServiceManager> sm = defaultServiceManager();

ALOGD("SystemServiceManager: %p", sm.get());
status_t ret;
ALOGD("FpService add");
//register MyService to ServiceManager
//FpService::instantiate();
FpService* srv = new MyTestService();
ALOGD("MyTestService: %p", srv);
ret = sm->addService(String16("hello.myservice"), srv);
// ret = sm->instantiate();

ALOGD("add services: %d", ret);

ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
IPCThreadState::self()->joinThreadPool();
return 0;
```

Comment: where are sources of `mytestDaemon` ?

Comment: @pskink I have post my source code on the thread, please help for this.